# How to map protected parent-class properties?

Tags: java, mapstruct

Consider the following classes:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class EntityMetaData {
  protected Integer createdBy;
  @CreatedDate protected Instant createdAt;
  protected Integer updatedBy;
  @LastModifiedDate protected Instant updatedAt;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DeliveryPartnerCredentials extends EntityMetaData {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private Integer companyNo;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private DeliveryPartner deliveryPartner;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Map<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<>();

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private EntityStatus status = EntityStatus.ACTIVE;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DPCModel {
  private Long id;
  private Integer companyNo;
  private DeliveryPartner deliveryPartner;
  private Map<String, String> credentials;
  private EntityStatus status;
  private Integer createdBy;
  private Instant createdAt;
  private Integer updatedBy;
  private Instant updatedAt;
}
```

I have created a Mapper that maps DeliveryPartnerCredentials to DPCModel:

```java
@Mapper
public interface CredentialsMapper {
  @Mapping(target = "createdBy", expression = "java(deliveryPartnerCredentials.getCreatedBy())")
  @Mapping(target = "createdAt", expression = "java(deliveryPartnerCredentials.getCreatedAt())")
  @Mapping(target = "updatedBy", expression = "java(deliveryPartnerCredentials.getUpdatedBy())")
  @Mapping(target = "updatedAt", expression = "java(deliveryPartnerCredentials.getUpdatedAt())")
  DPCModel entityToModel(DeliveryPartnerCredentials deliveryPartnerCredentials);

  DeliveryPartnerCredentials modelToEntity(DPCModel dpcModel);
}
```

To achieve this mapping, I had to add `Getters` and `Setters` to the `EntityMetaData` class for protected properties and then add individual lines of `@Mapping` for each property. Ideally, the `EntityMetaData` class should not have the `Getters` and `Setters` and there are *n* number of entities that extend to `EntityMetaData`. Mapping all those entities will require individual lines of `@Mapping` in each Mapper which sounds a bit tedious. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an abstraction, something like

```
public interface EntityMetaDataMapper<E extends EntityMetaData, M> {

    //All MapStruct generated mappers will override this method
    E modelToEntity(M model);

    //Method annotated with @AfterMapping will be hooked in modelToEntity() implemetations
    @AfterMapping
    default void withAuditFields(M sourceModel, @MappingTarget E entity) {
        //Map created/updated fields here
    }
}
```

and then

```
@Mapper
public interface CredentialsMapper extends EntityMetaDataMapper<DeliveryPartnerCredentials, DPCModel> {}
```

Other *n* entity mappers are inherited in the same way